# Mostrar variable PHP tras calcular su valor

Tags: php, variables

¿Cómo puedo mostrar el valor de sup para que sea igual al de totv si se pinta primero?. Todo se muestra en el mismo php, peor por necesidades se muestr aprimero la tabla que contiene sup pero el valor no se calcula hasta la siguiente tabla.

1ª tabla que se pinta. En valor $vrc se conoce ya pero el de $sup no. Debe ser el mismo de $totv

```
<table class="fixed_header2" style="font-family:verdana, arial; font-size:11px; padding-top:10px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="200px">Ref</th>
<th width="100px">Inmueble m<sup>2</sup></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
echo "<tr><td width=\"200px\">" . $vrc . "</td>";
echo "<td width=\"100px\">" . $sup . "</td></tr>";
?>
</tbody>
</table>
´´´´
$sup es el valor que debe aparecer cuando se conozca el valor de $totv.
2ª tabla que se pinta. Se pinta la segunda porque uno de sus valores depende de un valor de la primera
´´´´
<table class="fixed_header" style="font-family:verdana, arial; font-size:11px; padding-top:30px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="100px">Sup. total m<sup>2</sup></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$usoI1 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->debi->luso;
$aniocons = $xmlcat->bico->bi->debi->ant;
$refcati1 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->pc1;
$refcati2 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->pc2;
$refcati3 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->car;
$refcati4 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->cc1;
$refcati5 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->cc2;
$refcI1 = $refcati1 . $refcati2 . $refcati3 . $refcati4 . $refcati5;
$total=0;
foreach($xmlcat->bico->lcons->cons as $cons) {
$superficie = $cons->dfcons->stl;
echo "<td width=\"200px\">" . $elemento .  "</td>";
echo "<tr><td width=\"100px\">" . $superficie . "</td></tr>";
if($elemento=='V' || $elemento=='A' || $elemento=='AP' || $elemento=='SO')
$totv = $total+=$superficie;
else
$totv=0;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que quieres, qué se muestra ahora, qué debería mostrarse?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano lo que necesito es que $sup muestre el valor de $totv que no se sabe hasta el final del código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio te conviene no mezclar los cálculos con el HTML. Sacá todas las cuentas primero y después mostrá los resultados. De esa manera es indistinto que muestres primero porque ya tenés todo calculado.

Por otro lado, si el único motivo por el cual querés que la primera tabla aparezca primera es una cuestión de diseño, podrías cambiar el orden en el que aparecen usando `flex`.

**Solución 1:**

```php
<?php
$vrc = 'lo que sea';

$usoI1 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->debi->luso;
$aniocons = $xmlcat->bico->bi->debi->ant;
$refcati1 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->pc1;
$refcati2 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->pc2;
$refcati3 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->car;
$refcati4 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->cc1;
$refcati5 = $xmlcat->bico->bi->idbi->rc->cc2;
$refcI1 = $refcati1 . $refcati2 . $refcati3 . $refcati4 . $refcati5;
$total = 0;

foreach ($xmlcat->bico->lcons->cons as $cons) {
    $superficie = $cons->dfcons->stl;
    if ($elemento == 'V' || $elemento == 'A' || $elemento == 'AP' || $elemento == 'SO') {
        $totv = $total += $superficie;
    } else {
        $totv = 0;
    }
}

$sup = $totv;
?>

<table class="fixed_header2" style="font-family:verdana, arial; font-size:11px; padding-top:10px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="200px">Ref</th>
            <th width="100px">Inmueble m<sup>2</sup></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="200px"><?php echo $vrc ?></td>
            <td width="100px"><?php echo $sup ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="fixed_header" style="font-family:verdana, arial; font-size:11px; padding-top:30px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="100px">Sup. total m<sup>2</sup></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $elemento ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $superficie ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Algunas variables no se de donde salen, así que tal vez estén mal. Por otro lado, la segunda tabla tiene mal los `<tr>`, no se si la armé como necesitás.

---

**Solución 2:**
Imprimí la primera tabla al final y cambiá el orden en el que aparecen usando [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items):

```css
/* Orden de las tablas */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#table1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  order: 2;
}

#table2 {
  order: 1;
}

/* Diseño */
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

caption {
  padding: 0.35rem;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

th {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dee2e6;
}

td {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table id="table1">
    <caption>Tabla 1</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sup. total m<sup>2</sup></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>300 m<sup>2</sup></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="table2">
    <caption>Tabla 2</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Ref</th>
        <th>Inmueble m<sup>2</sup></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Sarasa</td>
        <td>200 m<sup>2</sup></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Solucionado con flex. Cierto que primero debería hacer los cálculos, pero no controlo mucho, estoy emepzando y como los valores me los da un foreach, si calculaba primero y mostraba después, sólo me salía un valor.